# Some issues concerning joint random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let the joint random variable $P[x;y]$ be

$P[x;y] = c[2x^2 + y^2], x=-1;0;1, y=1;2;3;4$

$=0$   $elsewhere$

So I had to find the value of $c$ that makes $P[x;y]$ a joint discrete random variable.

I think I did that right. I just add up all the probabilities where $x = -1;0;1$ and $y = 1;2;3;4$ and made it equal to 1. Then I solved for $c$ and got $c=\frac{1}{106}$. Please check this for me if you think I've done something wrong.

Now they asked to calculate the $E[y]$ and the next question asked if $x$ and $y$ are independent.

So. I was a bit confused with the whole $P[x;y]$ and how to split it up into $P[x]$ and $P[y]$ (if that's possible) and then how to work out the $E[y]$.

Comment: So you got the normalisation correct (barring mental arithmetic error) but your approach was correct..now you have to find the marginal probabilitys this done by summing over all x to get the y distribution, and similarly for the x distribution you sum over y. Then you take expectations with respect to the marginals. To get independence, I suggest going through notes that you have in terms of what criterion is required for that :).

Comment: I'm seeing something that looks like $E[Y] = \sum _{x} [{y}P[x;y]]$

Comment: That would work. Presumably this is an excerise to understand the joint distributions, I would advice derive the marginals first $$P(y) = \sum_{x}P(x,y)$$ and then compute the expectation for clarity..though your approach would work (skipping a few steps :))

Comment: I don't really understand the notation though. If we're only summing x's then which y values do we use?

Comment: sorry I was not clear before. you obtain the marginal probability for y as I shown above. Then you sum over all y after multiplying the marginal probability of y, $P(y)$, by y. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think what I'm confused about is how to I use that formula to calculate the marginal probability of y. Could you expand it for me? What I mean is. $P(y) = \sum _x P(x,y) = (-1, y) + (0,y) + (1,y)$ because it said sum of x's but I feel like I don't understand the notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the points above
$$
\begin{align}
P_Y(y) &=& \sum_{x = \lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace} c\left(2x^2 + y^2\right)\\
&=&c\left[\sum_{x = \lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace} 2x^2 + \sum_{x = \lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace}  y^2\right]\\
&=&c\left[2\cdot (-1)^2+ 2\cdot(0)^2+2\cdot(1)^2 + 3\cdot y^2\right] \\
&=& c\left(4+3y^2\right)
\end{align}
$$

now you can apply the formula as @Did.

Comment: Oh thanks. Now it's making more sense to me

Comment: so just to clarify. I can say. $E(y) = \sum_{y}{y}{\frac{1}{106}}({4 + 3y^2}) = (1)(\frac{1}{106})(4+3(1)^2) + (2)(\frac{1}{106})(4+3(2)^2) + (3)(\frac{1}{106})(4+3(3)^2) + (4)(\frac{1}{106})(4+3(4)^2)$

Comment: that seems ok to my eye there.

Comment: Thanks. So I suppose the place where I was confused is just that you only need to use the y's in the equation since you eliminated the x's when working out $P_y(y)$

Comment: yes, and as Did has shown the link between computing the expectation of Y with the joint distribution, and how that relates to the marginal :).

Answer (score 3):

$$E(Y)=\sum_{x,y}y\,P_{X,Y}(x,y)=\sum_yy\,P_Y(y),\qquad P_Y(y)=\sum_xP_{X,Y}(x,y)$$

Comment: If you were working out $E[X]$. Would it be: $E[X] = \sum_{x,y}x P_{X,Y}(x,y) = \sum_xP_x(x)$?

Comment: Tell me! (You *really* need to check one definition or two, say on WP, you know?)

Comment: Please just tell me if it's correct. It's not so easy to find this. At the end I meant $\sum_xxP_X(x)$

Comment: Yes, $E(X)=\sum_xxP_X(x)$, **by definition**. As I hinted at in my previous comment, this is the first formula on [the WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out the problem for you and I hope it helps to check with your answer.  I have done it in EXCEL what other responders have alluded to.  To verify your answer.[image]

Comment: No problem, Thank you Sir

Comment: Thanks. I got the same value for $E[Y]$ so this did help :)

Comment: Also. I see how you just used $P(1;1) and P(X=1)P(y=1)$. Do you think that's sufficient in a test or would they expect me to Show that $E[X+Y] = E[X]E[Y]$

Comment: What you have mentioned is the way to go, but this is a quick way to check if it is independent or not!

Comment: Alright thanks :)